# Preventing Firefox from visiting what's typed as search keywords in address bar

Tags: firefox

I often type keywords directly in Firefox's address bar in order to search Google. Sometimes Firefox attempts to add "www" and ".com" to these keywords and visit the resulting URL. This almost always fails. Is there any way to prevent this behavior and ensure that only Google searches are made?

Answer (score 2):

- Type `about:config` in the address bar
- Click "I'll be careful"
- Search for `browser.urlbar.autoFill`
- Right click `browser.urlbar.autoFill`
- click Toggle

You may need to do the same for `browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled`.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to work. FF attempted again to wrap my keyword with "www" and ".com"